# Laravel collection - echo value only if collection contains values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a Laravel collection which returns different values. I want to fill the form always with the first set of the collection, so far there are data available.

Right now I am debugging and found an error. If there aren't data available I get `Undefined offset: 0`. This is how I check if data are available and if yes it should fill out the form.

```
value="@php if($data){ echo $data[0]->client_id; } @endphp"
```

This is my full code:

```
<form class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
    <div class="form-horizontal show" role="form" id="customer_details">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h5>Kundendetails</h5>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="modal_cid">Kundennummer</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal_cid" value="@php if($data){ echo $data[0]->client_id; } @endphp" disabled="">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="modal_title">Anrede</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal_title" value="@php if($data){ echo $data[0]->title; } @endphp" autocomplete="honorific-prefix">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="modal_academic_title">Titel</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modal_academic_title" value="@php if($data){ echo $data[0]->academic_title; } @endphp" autocomplete="honorific-prefix">
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="modal_fname">Vorname</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                       <input type="name" class="form-control" id="modal_fname" value="@php if($data){ echo $data[0]->first_name; } @endphp" autocomplete="given-name">
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I fix this error and only fill out the form with the first set/row of the collection?

I have already tried out those solutions. Not working..

1. `value="@php if($data){ echo $data[0]->account_account_holder; } @endphp"`
2. `value="@php if($data[0){ echo $data[0]->account_account_holder; } @endphp"`
3. `value="@php if($data[0]->account_account_holder){ echo $data[0]->account_account_holder; } @endphp"`

Comment: If data is a collection, then there are several functions you can _chain_ with it, such as `$data->take(1)->has('account_account_holder')` check: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-has

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use isset() to check it first

```
@php if(isset($data[0])){ echo $data[0]->client_id; } @endphp
```

for more sure

```
@php if(isset($data[0]->client_id)){ echo $data[0]->client_id; } @endphp
```

Comment: Well... Thank you. It was too obviously.. Should have known that haha